eVisa applications in Scotland unsuccessful
Was invited by gov.uk email in July to transition to an eVisa.  Have tried MANY times and failed, likely because my (married) name is correct on my passport and incorrect on my BRP card.  Since passport is correct, I've used it to start application every time.  Early in process, I learned I'd need to give my BRP info also.  Have backed out of application so many times I now see "Cannot Start Yet" after every question.  Was advised by online "help" to clear my history or use another device.  Did both, neither worked.  And somewhere along the way, I saw that I cannot apply for a new BRP because expiration date, 31 Dec. 2024, is too close.

What’s your question?

You need to contact UKVI on 0300 790 6268 (option 2) and explain the situation like you did here. Make sure you mention you've tried the eVisa webchat but got nowhere through it.

Thanks - good advice.  The only "support" number I've called through all this where someone picked up right away.  They suggested I send all info to Applyonlinee-support@home office.gov.uk.  Double e is deliberate.  Awaiting reply.

@Cindy There's no space between home and office

Thanks, Crazydre.  No responses.  Re-sent email today to applyonlinee-support@homeoffice.gov.uk.

@Cindy If you get nothing within another month, call back on the support number and explain that
